# How do I find a PhD research area that will be commercially viable?

Tags: phd, job-search, job, industry

I want to find a PhD position which will guarantee my ability to obtain a job in industry as a researcher.
I need some ideas how to find a research field which companies will want to invest in and hire researchers in.
How do I find an area that will be commercially viable?

Comment: If you want a job in industry, do not do a PHD. Operating tools like openstack is not research. You can learn such tools on your own.

Comment: People mainly do a PHD because they love doing research. No piece of paper (including a PHD) can guarantee that you will get the ideal job you want.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific PhD position that will guarantee your ability to land an industry research position. What will guarantee you hire-ability will be your own skills and drive for an area of research. Yea most companies require that shiny piece of paper, but what they really want out of that is the abilities gained and refined during the process of earning that paper.  Show you have the ability for good research no matter what the topic and you will have more opportunities.

Comment: @scrappedcola *most companies require that shiny piece of paper* Nope.

Comment: i'll adjust to many who are looking for researchers require it, though I haven't seen a single technical research position that lacks that in the requirements.

Comment: Pick something with a lot of software engineering/scientific computing.  Those are very portable skills.

Comment: @user2379888, thanks please expand the answer I am looking for some thing like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are no guarantees when it comes to degrees and job prospects. I assume you mean "improve my chances" or "give me a high probability" of getting a job in industry.

Here's a procedure you use:

1. Identify the industries that hire a high number of PhDs. These data
   can be found at US Department of Labor and similar.  If you can't find
   any, start with Finance, Health Care (Drugs, Biotech), Chemicals, Oil & Gas,
   Information Services, and Government.
2. Identify the largest employers in each of these industries.
3. Likewise, identify the top employers of PhDs -- e.g. the National Labs.  This used to include Bell Labs, IBM, HP Labs, Microsoft Research, but all (but the last) have been decimated in the last 20 years.
4. Go to their web sites, find "Careers", and search on "PhD" keyword or criteria.  Read the job descriptions and find out what is common among them -- discipline, skills, experience, etc.

I think you'll find the common denominator is that the organizations that hire PhDs have a way to covert PhD skills and knowledge into money (i.e. via competitive advantage, marketable innovation, etc.)  If your #1 goal in getting a PhD is to get a job in industry for big $$, then you had better become an expert on how your PhD skills and knowledge will get converted to money.  This should lead you to study your target industry in great detail -- history, economics, strategy, and recent trends.